# "Authorization Required" error mantis api -- MantisConnect

Tags: mantis

I am getting an error when try access to mantis api using following url
`http://myurl/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php` using php curl.

```
{"error":"Authorization Required"}
```

Is there settings for admin to access mantis api?

Comment: This really isn't a MantisBT-related problem, we don't return errors on JSon format.

Answer (score 0):

I think my subscription is bronze now. Only silver and Gold subscription having api access.

http://www.mantishub.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=World%20Mantis%20Searchers